# Pig Latin Python Translator

Tags: python

I'm making a pig latin translator in python. I'd like to follow the rules of pig latin which state that it is not the first letter, but rather the first sound that moves to the end. As such, a word like "tree" becomes "eetray", and not "reetay". As such, I'd like to make the program detect whether a word has a digraph at the beginning. Here's my code so far:

```
import twoletterdigraphs
import threeletterdigraphs


pyg = 'ay'

original = input('Enter a word: ')

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    word = original.lower()

    if word[0] + word[1] + word[2] in threeletterdigraphs.threeLetter:
        first = word[0] + word[1] + word[2]
        new_word = word + first + pyg
        new_word = new_word[3:len(new_word)]
        print(new_word)
    elif word[0] + word[1] in twoletterdigraphs.twoLetter:
        first = word[0]+word[1]
        new_word = word + first + pyg
        new_word = new_word[2:len(new_word)]
        print(new_word)
    else:
        first = word[0]
        new_word = word + first + pyg
        new_word = new_word[1:len(new_word)]
        print(new_word)
else:
    print('empty')
```

twoletterdigraphs and threeletterdigraphs are python files containing nothing but a tuple with a list of digraphs mapped to a variable twoLetter or threeLetter. Here they are:

```
twoLetter = ["sh" "tr" "ch" "bl" "br" "cl" "cr" "dr" "fl" "fr" "gl" "gr" "pl" "pr" "sc" "sk" 
             "sl" "sm" "sn" "sp" "st" "sw" "th" "tr" "tw" "wh" "wr"]
```

and

```
threeLetter = ["sch" "scr" "shr" "sph" "spl" "spr" "squ" "str" "thr"]
```

When I run my code, It will only move the first letter to the end, regardless of what word I use. How can this be fixed?

Comment: eesay owhay otay eatecray ayay [inimalmay , ompletecay , andyay erifiablevay exampleyay](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your list elements in `twoLetter` and `threeLetter` should be comma-separated...

Comment: @JeffUK +1 for trolling.

Comment: If you don't enter at least a three character word this will fail because it checks the third character no matter what.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS Oh my god I'm an idiot. Thank you, the code is working now.

Comment: @IFunball I fixed this issue with an extra if statement. Thank you for telling me about this.